# Timeout connection to remote SQL Server within docker compose in mac os ventura 13.1

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js, connection-timeout

I have an application an running well using docker (docker image run on docker compose) on our self host server (that I don't know the network and routing config), but when I run it on my localhost macbook, it produce connection timeout to remote SQL Server.

This is the apps specs:

1. Node js alpine
2. Compose version 3.8
3. Connection to mssql using sequelize 6.8.0 & tedious 14.0.0
4. Docker desktop 4.18.0

Machine specs:
Macbook pro 2020 M1 chip with Mac OS Ventura 13.1

This is the docker compose configuration:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  api:
    container_name: mobile-apps-api-dev
    image: ${CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE}
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /Users/fhi-it-dev/Documents/server-mobile-apps-v2/uploads:/mobile-apps-api-dev/uploads
      - /Users/fhi-it-dev/Documents/server-mobile-apps-v2/share:/mobile-apps-api-dev/share
    ports:
      - "4002:4002"
    cpus: 0.7
    command: npm run start:dev
    networks:
      - "mynetwork"

  redis:
    image: redis:7.0.4
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /Users/fhi-it-dev/Documents/server-mobile-apps-v2/data:/mobile-apps-api-dev/data
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning --port 6379
    networks:
      - "mynetwork"

  redisFcm:
    image: redis:7.0.4
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /Users/fhi-it-dev/Documents/server-mobile-apps-v2/dataFcm:/mobile-apps-api-dev/dataFcm
    ports:
      - "6381:6381"
    command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning --port 6381
    networks:
      - "mynetwork"

networks:
  mynetwork:
    external: true
    driver: "bridge"
```

this is the error produced:

```
2023-05-03 08:51:45   original: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 172.17.221.183:1433 in 15000ms
2023-05-03 08:51:45       at Connection.connectTimeout (/mobile-apps-api-dev/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1232:26)
2023-05-03 08:51:45       at Timeout._onTimeout (/mobile-apps-api-dev/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1177:12)
2023-05-03 08:51:45       at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
2023-05-03 08:51:45       at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
2023-05-03 08:51:45     code: 'ETIMEOUT',
2023-05-03 08:51:45     isTransient: undefined
2023-05-03 08:51:45   }
2023-05-03 08:51:45 }
```

This IP is our SQL Server IP address: 172.17.221.183

Why it running well on ubuntu server, but timeout when running on local mac? is there need some network configuration in localhost?

Please help

Comment: 172.17.221.183 is in the 172.16.0.0/12 private non-routable address range (172.16.0.0-172.31.255.255). Is your Mac connected to the same private network infrastructure as the remote SQL Server? Do you  need to use an SSH or VPN tunnel instead?

Comment: That docker compose doesn't have an SQL server instance.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes i need VPN tunnel to connect SQL Server

Comment: @CetinBasoz no, cause i need this apps connect to remote SQL server, not inside docker compose.